# NSData UIImageJPEGRepresentation not writing to SQLite fmdb

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, fmdb

I am attempting to convert a jpeg to an nsdata object and then store that data in a blob column of an sqlite database using the fmdb wrapper.

e.g:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"house.jpeg" ];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into t1 values (null,?)", data ];
```

Where t1 is created something like:

```
[database executeUpdate:@"create table t1(rowid integer primary key autoincrement, house blob)" ];
```

Ideally I would then be able to pull the data out and convert it back to a jpeg like so:

```
NSString *query = @"select * from t1";

FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:query];

while ([ results next ]) 
{

    NSData *picData = [ results dataForColumn:@"house" ];
    UIImage *housePhoto = [ UIImage imageWithData:picData ];
}
```

I have used this type of model for other data types like strings, etc.. with no problem. In my current attempt I am using this model with a table of string columns and 1 blob column. When I write to the database, all of the strings are stored fine, but when I try to read back the blob column like above, I get null returned for the blob column. Prior to writing to the database I double checked to see that the NSData I am writing with was not null and did contain a jpeg representation and it did. Does a known issue jump out at anyone or am I just doing something wrong externally from this?

Comment: Did you check the resulting sqlite database to see if any data actually got stored in the column? That would help determine whether it's a problem writing the data in the first place vs reading it out after. You should also check to make sure `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` is returning a non-`nil` value, because it may actually return `nil` if the image has no data or if it's using an unsupported bitmap format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into t1 values (null,?)", data ];
```

Is always going to result in this string:

```
insert into t1 values (null,?)
```

As -stringWithFormat: doesn't understand that you are trying to bind data to the "?".

It looks like FMDatabase has an -executeQuery: method, which takes a variable number of arguments.  Try this instead:

```
[database executeQuery:@"insert into t1 values (null,?)", data];
```

If you manually open the database using sqlite3, is the original JPEG data there?

Warning: I'm accessing an ancient section in my brain, as I haven't done databases for a few years ;)

Comment: Great! Thanks :) You got me started on the right path. Turns out you need to call the executeUpdate method and use the variable arguments with it instead of creating your string ahead of time with the stringWithFormat method as it will give the incorrect query string as you have noted.